# How to convert comma-delimited string to list in Python? But including some comma

Tags: python, split

```
data = ['wrq~,p~,sdvvzrug,zzz edlgx frp dx\n',
        'wrq~,p~,sdv,vzrug,zzz jrrjoh frp dx\n']
for item in data:
    text1 = item.split(",")[0]
    text2 = item.split(",")[1]
    text3 = item.split(",")[2].strip()
    print(text1)
    print(text2)
    print(text3)
```

I'm using python to write and read files.The data was stored in comma-separated text file.
Then I'm using readlines() converted to list of strings. Then use split(",") seperate by comma.
However i need the output like this

```
text1=wrq~  
text2=p~,sdvvzrug 
text3=zzz edlgx frp dx
second string of the list will be the same 
text1=wrq~  
text2=p~,sdv,vzrug 
text3=zzz edlgx frp dx
```

Basic each string has three parts. either part maybe will contain some comma,so how to split string by comma and not remove the comma inside each part?

Comment: If I were you, I would change the delimiter in that file. I don't see another way around it. You can hardcode more information specific to that one file (e.g. the on line 1 string 2 has an internal comma), but that's very inefficient and troublesome.

Comment: You need to be able to define some rule that determines when a comma is a delimiter and when it isn't. The only possibility with your data would be if relevant parts of your string can be identified by their offset

Comment: Why don't you use newlines between the fields? Then you know each datapoint is made of 3 lines and you already have the output format you want. Or use `CSV` format with appropriate quoting (done automatically by the `csv` module)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are reading and writing the files you could choose another delimiter instead of "," like ";". Now if you want to use "," as a delimiter you could encapsulate the strings with comma with brackets: "some_str_with_comma_inside" so that you know what is going on and treat the file differently.
Finally why don't you use the csv module of python?

Comment: No point using CSV - It won't know how to decipher that

Comment: @JCaesar csv is actually a good option, it handles well quoting (provided you use libraries to write/read it and not custom code)

Comment: Thank you @mozway Can you help me with some sample code using the csv module that will provide the OP's output from their sample data?

Comment: @JCaesar [here you are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70862755/16343464)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv` with appropriate quoting, this is done automatically by the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

l = [['wrq~', 'p~,sdvvzrug', 'zzz edlgx frp dx'],
     ['wrq~', 'p~,sdv,vzrug', 'zzz jrrjoh frp dx'],
    ]

## ENCODING

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(l)

# file.csv
# wrq~,"p~,sdvvzrug",zzz edlgx frp dx
# wrq~,"p~,sdv,vzrug",zzz jrrjoh frp dx


## DECODING

with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    l2 = list(reader)

# l2
# [['wrq~', 'p~,sdvvzrug', 'zzz edlgx frp dx'],
#  ['wrq~', 'p~,sdv,vzrug', 'zzz jrrjoh frp dx']]
```

Comment: But you've changed the format of the input data! The OP doesn't have it like that!

Comment: @JCaesar no, the input data is something OP must have **BEFORE**, otherwise this is impossible to unambiguously solve the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code will produce the output you've asked for but may not be a generic solution:

```
data = ['wrq~,p~,sdvvzrug,zzz edlgx frp dx\n', 'wrq~,p~,sdv,vzrug,zzz jrrjoh frp dx\n']

for d in data:
    t = d.split(',')
    print(t[0])
    print(','.join(t[1:-1]))
    print(t[-1])
```

**Output**:

```
wrq~
p~,sdvvzrug
zzz edlgx frp dx

wrq~
p~,sdv,vzrug
zzz jrrjoh frp dx
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want text1 and text2 to be the first and last part of the comma separated list (if that's not the case, you will have to provide a rule to determine which parts should be grouped together).

You can assign the first, middle and last parts to the 3 variables using unpacking for the middle, then join the middle part back together by re-introducing the commas:

```
data = ['wrq~,p~,sdvvzrug,zzz edlgx frp dx\n',
        'wrq~,p~,sdv,vzrug,zzz jrrjoh frp dx\n']
for item in data:
    text1,*text2,text3 = item.strip().split(',')  # text2 will be a tuple
    text2 = ",".join(text2)                       # make it a string again
    print(text1)
    print(text2)
    print(text3)
wrq~
p~,sdvvzrug
zzz edlgx frp dx
wrq~
p~,sdv,vzrug
zzz jrrjoh frp dx
```